# Finding equivalence classes for fractionalPart

Tags: equivalence-relations, formal-proofs

Definition: fractionalpart[x] takes all digits to the right of the decimal point and drops the others. e.g. fractionalpart[123.456] = .456

Define a relation R on R(set of all reals) if fractionalpart[x] =fractionalpart[y].

I understand how to test if this is an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, and transitive) but, **how can I find the equivalence classes?**

Is it just the set of all real numbers that have the same numbers to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: Yes. The integer part doesn‘t matter anymore, so we might as well treat it as though it is zero. Therefore the set of equivalence classes can be identified with $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, the reals modulo $1$.

Comment: why treat it as 0? I don't see how the reals modulo 1 is the set of equivalence classes. If I take 123.456 as an element from the reals, the equivalence class isn't a set consisting of 0. b/c 0 and fractionalpart[123.456] are not related.

Comment: The set of ALL equivalence classes corresponds to the reals modulo $1$, i.e. there is one representative per class between $0$ and $1$. For example, $123.456$ is in the same equivalence class as $0.456$. $0$ is in the same class as $1$, or $-5$.

Comment: Your definition of fractional part is not quite right (or at least not the usual one) in case x is negative.